# Configuring a MySQL Database using Grail 2.4.4 (Unable to create initial connections of pool)

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I'm a really beginner in Grails technology. I installed the IDE Groovy/Grails Tool Suite™ (GGTS, Grails 2.4.4) for Windows 64bits.

The environment path has been correctly updated concerning the JDK and Grails.

I created a new project called 'test', added a new domain class called 'test.User' as follow:

```
package test

class User {

    Integer id
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
        id(blank:false, unique:true)
        firstName(blank:false)
        lastName(blank:false)
    }
}
```

applied static scaffolding to generate the corresponding UserController and views associated with CRUD actions.

To check if my data model is working with H2 database I made some updates into the DataSource.groovy file and it works: I've added a new user throw the application and when I run the command SELECT* on my table USER (using grails dbconsole) and I have my new user entry displayed. So, until here all is ok!

But now I want to connect my application with an alternative SQL database using a different JDBC connector. I chose (for sake of compatibility) the one proposed within my BuildConfig.groovy file and uncommented it:

```
runtime mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29
```

When I run the application 'run-app' (by default I think we are in development environment) I noticed the dependency mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar has been added into my .m2 directory (C:\Users\my_user_name.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.29). So I think the dependency is correctly registered within a kindof MAVEN file within Grails. However the file does not appear into the ivy-cache directory. Is it normal ?

My BuildConfig.groovy file content:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        //test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Concerning the DataSource.groovy file I replaced the line concerning the driver name:

```
driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
```

by

```
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

and for each environment (I know I only use development environment but it's just to avoid some errors) I replaced the followings lines:

```
url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
```

by

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
```

I've also added just below the default username and password (as root user) + the driver class name as follow (for each environment again):

```
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "root"
password = ""
```

Here's my DataSource.groovy file content:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    //driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            //url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the application I have the following error:

```
ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
```

Here's the whole error stack:

```
2016-08-23 16:18:58,040 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1129 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    358 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly . . . . . . in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO                   in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     46 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
->>   79 | socketConnect                 in java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    345 | doConnect                     in java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
|    206 | connectToAddress . . . . . .  in     ''
|    188 | connect                       in     ''
|    172 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in java.net.PlainSocketImpl
|    392 | connect                       in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
|    589 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in java.net.Socket
|    538 | connect                       in     ''
|    434 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    244 | <init>                        in     ''
|    256 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory
|    308 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly             in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    834 | <init>                        in     ''
|     46 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect                       in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2016-08-23 16:19:00,132 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1129 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    358 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly . . . . . . in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO                   in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     46 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
->>   79 | socketConnect                 in java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    345 | doConnect                     in java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
|    206 | connectToAddress . . . . . .  in     ''
|    188 | connect                       in     ''
|    172 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in java.net.PlainSocketImpl
|    392 | connect                       in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
|    589 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in java.net.Socket
|    538 | connect                       in     ''
|    434 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    244 | <init>                        in     ''
|    256 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory
|    308 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly             in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    834 | <init>                        in     ''
|     46 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect                       in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2016-08-23 16:19:02,194 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1129 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    358 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly . . . . . . in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO                   in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     46 | <init>                        in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . . . . . . . . . . . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
->>   79 | socketConnect                 in java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl
Error |
2016-08-23 16:19:02,205 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1129 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    358 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO in     ''
|    834 | <init> .  in     ''
|     46 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
->>   79 | socketConnect in java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    345 | doConnect in java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
|    206 | connectToAddress in     ''
|    188 | connect   in     ''
|    172 | connect . in java.net.PlainSocketImpl
|    392 | connect   in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
|    589 | connect . in java.net.Socket
|    538 | connect   in     ''
|    434 | <init> .  in     ''
|    244 | <init>    in     ''
|    256 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory
|    308 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2498 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2535 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2320 | createNewIO in     ''
|    834 | <init>    in     ''
|     46 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    416 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    347 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    266 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with errorJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

It seems Grails cannot find the driver or someting like that. However we've seen that the JAR file has been registered within .m2 directory. I wonder one thing: does this JAR file need to appear in the list of Grails dependencies:

[image]

The whole list is not on the picture but the file does not appear in the list. Is it normal ? Does the file must only appears within the .m2 directory (within the Ivy-cache this is the same, the file is not present) ? Do you think the dependency is available when I run the application ? Does Grails recognize the driver throw the classpath ?

I'm really lost.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Note that MySQL JDBC Driver classes are shown in your error trace. This is an indication that the MySQL JDBC jar *is* being used by your application. Failure to find the JDBC driver would be a different exception altogether. The problem is that your application isn't able to connect to your MySQL instance. Have you configured the Datasource correctly (URL, credentials)? Your sample code shows a blank password for the MySQL root user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But I would say follow steps below one by one:

1. Check if mysql server is installed on your machine. Case might be that you only have Mysql-client installed.
2. In your DataSource.groovy I see many things either missing or not configures properly. Few i noticed are:
   a) missing dialect configuration
   b) missing port no. to connect to server

Below is corrected DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    //driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"//you had a missing port here
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            //url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it help!! Let me know if you face any issue further after the new DataSource.groovy.

Comment: Thank you! It was obvious. I forgot to install MySQL server :). I told you, I'm a newbie! Now concerning the DataSource.groovy file, it's not necessary to provide the SQL hibernate 'dialect'. I think it's a default statement within Grails (but I think it's better to precise it anyway). And it's not necessary to precise the port too (I'm in localhost and the line 'grails.server.port.http' is not precise in the BuildConfig.groovy file so it's by default '8080' for me). So, thank you again for your help! Bye.